# Plotly: How do I set ylim and xlim for a map?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly

**Aim:**
I am trying to create an interactive version of a ggplot2 map using plotly (via ggplotly).

**Problem:** Plotly adds additional space above and below the chart rather than "stretching" the chart like it should (see images for example).

**Example**

What I want (example made in ggplot2):

[image]

What I'm getting (example made in plotly):

[image]

I understand that aspect.ratio is not supported in ggplotly but is there any other way to remove the space above and below whilst keeping the x-axis (-12,2) and y-axis (50,60) limits as they are

**Code:**

```
library(maps)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

boundaries <- ggplot2::map_data("world", region=c("UK","Ireland","France","Norway"))

map <- ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data=boundaries, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group), color="black", fill="white") +
  coord_sf(xlim=c(-12, 2), ylim=c(50,60)) +
  theme(aspect.ratio = 1.2)

show(map)

visual <- ggplotly(map, height=1.2*400, width=400, tooltip=c("text"), hoverinfo='hide', 
                               dynamicTicks=F) %>%
  layout(xaxis=list(autorange=F, range=c(-12, 2)), yaxis = list(autorange=F, range=c(50,60)))

show(visual)
```

**To replicate the problem:**

> OS: Windows 10 
> IDE: RStudio 
> R: R 3.6.1

Comment: I can replicate your issue. You can work around this by setting the height and width to match the ratio of the ranges (10 deg long to 14 deg lat). Close to your size is height = 300, width = 420. It's not pretty, and it's not the correct aspect ratio, but it excludes all of the extra area on the vertical axis.

Comment: Hi Ben, agreed that this semi-works: removes the empty space as requested but squashes the map too much sadly!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using `coord_sf` which is intended for the special class of sf data frames rather than the polygons that come with `ggplot`. You could use a package like `rnaturalearth` to easily obtain data in this format. Here, I have selected a high-res image, but if you struggle to install `rnaturalearthhires`, just select "medium" for map size.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(rnaturalearth)
library(sf)

df <- ne_countries(country = c("United Kingdom", "Ireland", "France", "Norway"),
                   returnclass = "sf",
                   scale = "large")

map <- ggplot(df) +
  geom_sf(color = "black", fill = "white") +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(-12, 2), ylim = c(50, 60))

show(map)
```

[image]

and we get the plotly map like this:

```r
visual <- ggplotly(map, height = 1.2 * 600, width = 600, tooltip=c("text"), 
                   hoverinfo='hide', dynamicTicks = FALSE) 

show(visual)
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

**For information, if you're using R in Power BI service, this is how you do it:**

You can get the desired result by adding a scaleratio to the xaxis option in layout (see code below).

```
library(maps)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

boundaries <- ggplot2::map_data("world", region=c("UK","Ireland","France","Norway"))

map <- ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data=boundaries, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group), color="black", fill="white") +
  coord_sf(xlim=c(-12, 2), ylim=c(50,60)) 

show(map)

visual <- ggplotly(map, height=1.2*400, width=400, tooltip=c("text"), hoverinfo='hide', 
 dynamicTicks=F) %>%
  layout(xaxis=list(scaleratio=0.6))

show(visual)
```

*Power BI service does not support rnaturalearth as per the accepted answer (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/service-r-packages-support)

[image]

Comment: Nice! This is a valuable contribution for others that use both R, Plotly and PowerBI!